# Randomly choose between of +, -, or * and apply it to two numbers

Tags: java, arrays, random, numbers, operation

Good day

I am new to java and would like to know if there is a way for me to randomly choose between multiplication and addition and apply it to two numbers.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes there is a way.  Perhaps you can provide more details in your question, even some code that is just missing the part you can't figure out.  Where are the numbers coming from?  Are they integers, floats?  Do you know how to use a random number generator?  What part are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess a code like the following could work:

```
// given two number a, b

double rand = Math.random();
if (rand > 0.5)
   c = a*b;
else
   c = a+b;

// c is the result of the addition/multiplication
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put all the possible operations in a `List` as `BinaryOperator`s, then choose a random index each time.

```java
List<BinaryOperator<Integer>> ops = List.of(Integer::sum, (a,b)->a-b, (a,b)->a*b);
int a = 1, b = 2; // numbers to apply operator to
int result = ops.get(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(ops.size())).apply(a, b);
System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Place the operators into an array and select a random index value for that array:

```
String[] operators = {"+", "-", "*", "/"};
int randomOperatorIndex = new java.util.Random().nextInt(operators.length);
int num1 = 24;
int num2 = 12;
double ans = 0.0d;
switch (randomOperatorIndex) {
    case 0:   // + 
        ans = num1 + num2;
        break;
    case 1:   // - 
        ans = num1 - num2;
        break;
    case 2:   // * 
        ans = num1 * num2;
        break;
    case 3:   // / 
        ans = num1 / num2;
        break;
}
 
System.out.println(num1 + " " + operators[randomOperatorIndex] 
                   + " " + num2 + " = " + ans);
```